# regular expression not to allow zero

Tags: regex, validation

regular expression not to allow zero

it should allow 0.0000001 as value but should not allow to enter 0.

I need validator not javascript

Comment: how about just validating that it is a number, then doing `val != 0`?

Comment: I treid rangevalidator and regularexpression validation with initialvalue= 0 but its not working for me

Comment: @Marc B - i dont want to use that javascript that i can do i need do this with the help of asp.net validator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think all you need is this `^(?=.*[1-9])\d*\.?\d*$`

But, you could get fancy and allow only a single leading zero if its before a decimal point.
`^(?=.*[1-9])(?:[1-9]\d*\.?|0?\.)\d*$`

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" 
     ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ErrorMessage="Input is not valid." 
     ValidationExpression="^(?=.*[1-9])(?:[1-9]\d*\.?|0?\.)\d*$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

Comment: This also matches strings ending in a point, like `1.`

That case can be fixed by using: `^(?=.*[1-9])\d*\.?\d+$`

Comment: @mantish - The whole idea of this fancy regular expression is to allow valid numbers. The rest is just anything but zero. In reality `(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)` is the only way to validate a number.

Answer (score 1):

a regexp like that?

```
       ([1-9](\.[0-9]+)?)|(0\.[0-9]*[1-9])
```

looks like working ;-)

if you remove the braces it looks more understandable:

```
       [1-9](\.[0-9]+)? | 0\.[0-9]*[1-9]
```

Comment: tried here:

http://www.sweeting.org/mark/html/revalid.php

and worked, use the upper version with braces

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow both **Positive** or **Negative** numbers but not 0:

```
^(-?.*[1-9])\d*\.?\d*$
```