# awk: replace second column if not zero

Tags: regex, unix, if-statement, awk

I'm trying to use `awk` to check the second column of a three column set of data and replace its value if it's not zero.  I've found [this regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081130/regular-expression-not-to-allow-zero) to find the non-zero numbers, but I can't figure out how to combine `gsub` with `print` to replace the contents and output it to a new file.  I only want to run the `gsub` on the second column, not the first or third.  Is there a simple `awk` one-liner to do this?  Or am I looking at doing something more complex?  I've even tried doing an expression to check for zero, but I'm not sure how to do an if/else statement in `awk`.

The command that I had semi-success with was:

`awk '$2 != 0 {print $1, 1, $3}' input > output`

The problem is that it didn't print out the row if the second column was zero.  This is where I thought either `gsub` or an if/else statement would work, but I can't figure out the `awk` syntax.  Any guidance on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remember that in awk, anything that is not 0 is true (though any string that is not "0" is also true).  So:

```
awk '$2 { $2 = 1; print }' input > output
```

The `$2` evaluates to true if it's not `0`.  The rest is obvious.  This replicates your script.

If you want to print all lines, including the ones with a zero in $2, I'd go with this:

```
awk '$2 { $2 = 1 } 1' input > output
```

This does the same replacement as above, but the `1` at the end is short-hand for "true".  And without a statement, the default statement of `{print}` is run.

Is this what you're looking for?

In action, it looks like this:

```
[ghoti@pc ~]$ printf 'none 0 nada\none 1 uno\ntwo 2 tvo\n'
none 0 nada
one 1 uno
two 2 tvo
[ghoti@pc ~]$ printf 'none 0 nada\none 1 uno\ntwo 2 tvo\n' | awk '$2 { $2 = 1 } 1'      
none 0 nada
one 1 uno
two 1 tvo
[ghoti@pc ~]$
```

Comment: This ended up working, though for some reason, it indented the beginning of the lines that had a zero value in the second column.  The non-zero values were replaced as expected, however.  The answer @perreal gave had indentation as well.  Any explanation behind that?

Comment: Yup.  When you change any fields in the line, awk rewrites the line so the output consists of fields separted by OFS.  If you don't replace `$2`, then awk leaves the line as-is, so the output line is identical to the input line.  If you want consistent output, you can, for example, also set `$1 = $1` to force the rewrite on every line.

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you want?

```
awk '$2 != 0 {print $1, 1, $3} $2 == 0 {print}' input > output
```

or with sed:

```
sed 's/\([^ ]*\) [0-9]*[1-9][0-9]* /\1 1 /' input > output
```

Comment: The `awk` in this answer ended up doing the trick, though as I mentioned above, it indented the beginning of the lines.  Not sure why.